# delay timer in gwt on quick sort

Tags: java, gwt, delay

I'm writing a quick sort algorithm in GWT, between each iteration I'm trying to print the current status.

This is the method

```
private int partition(int[] list_of_numbers, int first, int last) {

        int pivot = list_of_numbers[first];
        int up = first;
        int down = last;

        do {
            while ((up < last) && pivot >= list_of_numbers[up]) {
                up++;
            }
            while (pivot < list_of_numbers[down]) {
                down--;
            }
            if (up < down) {
                swap(list_of_numbers, up, down);
                sortedResult.setText( array_to_string(list_of_numbers));
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, sortedResult.getText());

            }
        } while (up < down);
        swap(list_of_numbers, first, down);
        sortedResult.setText( array_to_string(list_of_numbers));

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, sortedResult.getText());
        return down;
    }
```

It works really well and we can see from the logger that it puts out the following

```
30, 3, 23, 7, 77, 46, 62, 91, 89, 22, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
30, 3, 23, 7, 22, 46, 62, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
22, 3, 23, 7, 30, 46, 62, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
22, 3, 7, 23, 30, 46, 62, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
7, 3, 22, 23, 30, 46, 62, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 46, 62, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 40, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 46, 40, 91, 89, 77, 48, 96, 32, 62, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 46, 40, 32, 89, 77, 48, 96, 91, 62, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 89, 77, 48, 96, 91, 62, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 89, 77, 48, 96, 91, 62, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 89, 77, 48, 62, 91, 96, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 62, 77, 48, 89, 91, 96, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 62, 48, 77, 89, 91, 96, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 48, 62, 77, 89, 91, 96, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 48, 62, 77, 89, 91, 96, 95, 
3, 7, 22, 23, 30, 32, 40, 46, 48, 62, 77, 89, 91, 95, 96,
```

but on the output to the screen it will only display the last iteration

[image: output on gui]

I would like to put a delay of 1 second after each sort where the user can see the current array.

I'm not sure how to use the timer in this case. As well I don't know if it is changing the value each time so fast that I only see the last one or if it's only changing it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search yields a page guiding you through delaying calculations and updating the interface.

You can find it [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html).

Comment: that hasn't been working how I want. it will delay the time before putting out the answer but it will only print the final answer not the answer at each iteration with a delay in between. even though it's running in the loop

Comment: i'm not familiar with GWT, but this sounds like you have to update the display after the information gets updated.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?85440-SOLVED-Content-Panel-Add-or-refresh-content